# Systemctl file could not get AWS Credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, systemd

> Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]: Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Cannot load the credentials
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at demokinesis.kinesis.demoKinesis.init(demoKinesis.java:43)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at demokinesis.kinesis.demoKinesis.main(demoKinesis.java:48)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         ... 5 more
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS credential profiles file not found in the given 
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.ProfilesConfigFileLoader.loadProfiles(ProfilesConfig
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.loadProfiles(ProfilesConfigFile.java:214)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.(ProfilesConfigFile.java:139)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.(ProfilesConfigFile.java:128)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.(ProfilesConfigFile.java:96)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsP
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         at demokinesis.kinesis.demoKinesis.init(demoKinesis.java:41)
>   Mar 07 13:40:51 abhishek-X555LAB java[19921]:         ... 6 more

Systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=service file description
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Java code:

```
private static AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
AWSCredentials credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
```

Comment: Systemd unit by default run as root, your credentials provider is probably expecting credentials somewhere in home directory of current user. either explicitly set user in unit file (`User=xxx`) or copy necessary files to root's home dierctory

Comment: into `[Service]` section. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot

Comment: @rkosegi worked :) Thank you.